# Can not get Xpath to fetch a nodeList

Tags: php, xpath

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$url = 'http://thepiratebay.is/browse/200/0/7';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$x = new \DOMXPath($dom);
$nodeList = $x->query('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr');
foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
    die(var_dump($node));
}
```

Gives me the error:

```
"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"
```

Not sure why xpath doesn't work on that domain?

Comment: Have you `var_dump`ed the contents of `$html` just to make sure your XPath query corresponds to the structure of what you're fetching?

Comment: I couldn't find `tbody` anywhere in the source of the page either...

Comment: @Havelock +1. In cases where the error is because a parsed content is not being seen, it is very helpful to have the content in question also to be pasted as part of the question (at least the relevant part, in case it is a huge data - or maybe in some online HTML pastebin)

Comment: @Raidenace the OP has provided the URL... Right mouse click -> show page source (in FF)

Comment: @Havelock - many systems do not give access to torrent sites..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right you'd like to get all the titles in that table. I'd suggest an easier, yet more specific XPath query, i.e.

```
$nodeList = $x->query('//div[@class="detName"]');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xOuhuB)

Comment: I used firebug's 'copy xpath' to get the xpath. Do you by any chance know why that doesn't work? I'll go study the xpath now to write it manually :p

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie, to be honest, I can't tell you why Firebug didn't get it right. But in my opinion nothing beats knowing the background of things when using tools to help you.